# Nested Go Structs for JSON marshaling with optional structs

Tags: json, go, struct

I'm trying to initialize a nested struct to then marshal into json for an API response. The challenge I'm hitting is one of the components (a slice of structs) can have n number of members but of one of two possible types (text, image).

The JSON I want to create looks like this:

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "message_parts": [
        {
          "text": {
            "content": "dfdffd"
          }
        },
        {
          "image": {
            "url": "https://image.jpg"
          }
        }
      ],
      "actor_id": "44444444",
      "actor_type": "agent"
    }
  ],
  "channel_id": "44444444",
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "44444444"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the message_parts slice, that can contain at least one of text or image but possibly one of each.

My structs look like this currently:

```
   Type messagePayload struct {
        Messages  []Messages `json:"messages"`
        Status    string     `json:"status,omitempty"`
        ChannelID string     `json:"channel_id"`
        Users     []Users    `json:"users"`
    }
    type Messages struct {
        MessageParts []MessageParts `json:"message_parts"`
        ActorID      string         `json:"actor_id"`
        ActorType    string         `json:"actor_type"`
    }

    type Users struct {
        ID string `json:"id"`
    }
    type Text struct {
        Content string `json:"content,omitempty"`
    }
    type MessageParts struct {
        Text  *Text  `json:"text,omitempty"`
        Image *Image `json:"image,omitempty"`
    }
    type Image struct {
        URL string `json:"url,omitempty"`
    }
```

I'm really struggling to initialize this in a way that not show up in the json if they're not present.

here's where I'm at but it obviously doesn't work:

```
payload := &messagePayload{
    Messages: []Messages{
        {
            MessageParts: []MessageParts{
                {
                    &Text{
                        Content: text,
                    },
                },
                {
                    &Image{
                        URL: mediaurl,
                    },
                },
            },
            ActorID:   agentID,
            ActorType: "agent",
        }},
    ChannelID: channelid,
    Users: []Users{
        {
            ID: user,
        },
    },
}
```

EDIT:
Thanks to hint below and a few other findings, I've found the best way is to initalize the payload and then add the slices for text and images as needed:
https://play.golang.org/p/Pmmv00spcI6

Comment: try that, https://play.golang.org/p/Pp1DobOBfa5

Comment: That works, the problem is when text or mediaurl are empty ("") it's not omitting them `{"messages":[{"message_parts":[{"text":{"content":"LOL"}},{"image":{}}],"actor_id":"id","actor_type":"agent"}],"channel_id":"cid","users":[{"id":"user1"}]}
`

Comment: Could I initialize MessageParts first with either/both text/image, then use that to initialize the overall payload?

Comment: Or initialize the payload, then append slices to messageparts with append?

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, I was able to find a solution- you need to initialize the payload without the text or image data, then append them to the MessageParts slice:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type messagePayload struct {
    Messages  []Messages `json:"messages"`
    Status    string     `json:"status,omitempty"`
    ChannelID string     `json:"channel_id"`
    Users     []Users    `json:"users"`
}
type Messages struct {
    MessageParts []MessageParts `json:"message_parts"`
    ActorID      string         `json:"actor_id"`
    ActorType    string         `json:"actor_type"`
}

type Users struct {
    ID string `json:"id"`
}
type Text struct {
    Content string `json:"content,omitempty"`
}
type MessageParts struct {
    Text  *Text  `json:"text,omitempty"`
    Image *Image `json:"image,omitempty"`
}
type Image struct {
    URL string `json:"url,omitempty"`
}

func main() {

    payload := &messagePayload{
        Messages: []Messages{
            {
                MessageParts: []MessageParts{

                },
                ActorID:   "id",
                ActorType: "agent",
            }},
        ChannelID: "cid",
        Users: []Users{
            {
                ID: "user1",
            },
        },
    }
    var text= new(MessageParts)
    text.Text = &Text{Content: "LOL"}
        var image = new(MessageParts)
        image.Image= &Image{URL: "https://"}
    payload.Messages[0].MessageParts = append(payload.Messages[0].MessageParts, *text)
    payload.Messages[0].MessageParts = append(payload.Messages[0].MessageParts, *image)
    m, err := json.Marshal(payload)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error, ", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(m))
}
```